# Chat and web socket not connecting

Tags: go, websocket

I'm implementing chat with html5 web sockets in go lang and having errors both at client and server end.

**Client Error:**

> WebSocket connectiont to 'ws://192.168.16.90:4000` failed: Invalid HTTP version string GET

**Server Error:**

continous looping of the following log message in the terminal,

> connection closed\n received message:\n message sent:\n

**Server Code:**

```
func (s *Service) InitializeService() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":4000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Chat server started to listen on port ", listener.Addr())

    defer listener.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("A new connection accepted.")

        go listenConnection(conn)
    }
}

func listenConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        buffer := make([]byte, 1400)
        dataSize, err := conn.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("connection closed")
        }

        data := buffer[:dataSize]
        fmt.Println("received message: ", string(data))

        _, err = conn.Write(data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("message sent: ", string(data))
    }
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
var connection = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.16.90:4000");

connection.onopen = function() {
    console.log("onopen");
    connection.send("Ping");
};

connection.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log("WebSocket Error", error);
};

connection.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("Server: ", e.data);
};
```

Comment: Looks like the websocket protocol is not implemented on the server, just a network connection

Comment: I would save yourself a lot of pain and try using Gorilla websockets.  https://github.com/gorilla/websocket  There is more to websockets then just a tcp connection, there is the web socket protocol to contend with: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455

Comment: I'd use gorilla as a last resort since I need to learn the underlying work, and the chat system is basic, peer to peer conversation only and I've time for this. If someone can help me with some code to start with (sending receiving messages) and show some direction to research more, I'd appreciate.

Comment: @Developer If you look at the link I sent you can see in examples/chat: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat

Comment: I've seen gorilla implementation but would like to see how the native platform approaches the sockets, if anyone can modify the above code to make it work with web sockets without gorilla, that'd achieve the objective

Comment: @Mark can you help fix it, what am I missing in here?

Comment: @Developer, you're missing code implementing the websocket protocol. sberry helpfully linked to the definition of the protocol, describing what needs to be done. If you don't want to do this yourself, sberry's other helpful link to Gorilla is a defacto standard implementation of the protocol, providing a well tested, production ready solution. The protocol isn't implemented by the Go standard library, but the Go authors wrote [x/net/websocket](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket). Note they also recommend Gorilla. Either use a package, or read the source to guide your implementation.

Comment: Ok. It's clearing things up a little bit. Tomorrow I'll read both specs and gorilla source code to understand more how it's done at the lower level. I'll still ask question in comments for something I don't get.